# Using Lynx to run a PHP script in CentOS

Tags: php, linux, apache, cron

I need to use an Apache handler to run a PHP script, rather than running it through CLI. I'm using APC user cache, which stores variables using the Apache process. If I run my PHP script through CLI, then it won't have access to the APC variables.

A possible solution is creating a directory restricted to localhost and putting my scripts in there. Then, I can use a browser to run the PHP scripts. However, I'm not too experienced with Linux and I don't know how to implement this. Here's how I need it to work:

1. One of the cron job fires.
2. The cron job opens the PHP script using a web browser.
3. After the PHP script is finished processing, the web browser closes.

I don't know how to close the browser once the task is finished. Also, multiple PHP scripts will be running simultaneously (called by different cron jobs), I'm not sure how this will work. I'm using the Lynx browser on CentOS.

Comment: `wget` will work as it just requests the resource.  You can save the result to a file or discard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Debian/Ubuntu I can run a script using lynx, say

```
/usr/bin/lynx -source 'url'
```

For eg:

```
/usr/bin/lynx -source http://google.com
```

Once execution is completed, the browser quits default.

Answer (score -1):

```
lynx -source [url]   Would not work!
```

The above recommendation, using the -source option would not run the php script, it simply lists the source code of the page.

I have often thought about how lynx gets closed on my hosted server, as it is called every day (for the past 10 years or more!) from my cron to run my php housekeeping scripts. Perhaps they all sit there doing nothing until the server gets rebooted...

I think the best solution is by using wget...

```
wget  [url]  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: You’re wrong. The `-source` flag causes lynx to dump the source code it gets from the server and then exit.  Emphasis on “from the server”. That’s the HTML source code, not the PHP source code. The server executes the PHP to generates the HTML source code before sending it to the client. Nothing the client can do can make the server send it the PHP source code. If it could, then that would be a serious security problem.